# Public Calendar's URL in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, salesforce-classic, calendar

We have home page components in classic view where a user can click on different public calendars link to view the particular shared public calendar.
In classic, if we change the calendar to any shared public calendar, the URL of the page also will be changed. This is the URL that we used in home page components.

When we try to do the same for lightning experience using the app builder for the home page, we couldn't able to fetch the URL. If we give the same URL that we gave in the classic view, it is redirecting to classic view.
In Lightning, if we add 'Other Calendars' in the calendar view, the URL of the page is not changing with the parameters for the selected calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same dilema  when migrating a client to Lightning. I'm surprised there were no responses. What did you end up doing to replace the Classic Home Page links?